# List file paths that match a regex when both path and filename contain wildcard

Tags: java, regex, file

Our system allows both the folder and file could be in regex format. For example

```
/dir1*/abcd/efg.? is legal. 

/dir* could match /dira and also /dirb/cde
```

I want to find all files that match this pattern. To eliminate unnecessary operation, I want to get the root directory to start the file listing and filtering.

Is there any effective way to get the root directory of a regex path pattern?

Several test cases:

```
/abc/def*/bc return /abc
/abc/def*    return /abc
/ab.c/def*   return /
/ab\.c/def*  return /ab.c
```

Comment: What is the standard for the regex in file/folder path? Is it the same as bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited:** Added handling of relative paths

```
String path;
String root = path.replaceAll( "((?<=/)|((?<=^)(?=\\w)))(?!(\\w|\\\\\\.)+/.*).*", "" ) );
```

Here's a test:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    String[] paths = {"/abc/def*/bc", "/abc/def*", "/ab.c/def*", "/ab\\.c/def*", "abc*", "abc/bc"};
    for ( String path : paths ) {
        System.out.println( path + " --> " + path.replaceAll( "((?<=/)|((?<=^)(?=\\w)))(?!(\\w|\\\\\\.)+/.*).*", "" ) );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/abc/def*/bc --> /abc/
/abc/def* --> /abc/
/ab.c/def* --> /
/ab\.c/def* --> /ab\.c/
abc* --> 
abc/bc --> abc/
```

You can fine tune it from there.

Comment: This just returns an empty String for all the test cases.

Comment: @Bohemian: Indeed. There are probably other characters that can be escaped too, but as you say, this should be easy to finetune. +1

Comment: What about relative path, for example "abc*" return "" and "abc/bc*" return "abc"? @Behemian

Comment: @JermaineXu You didn't ask about relative paths, and none of your examples were relative paths, but I have edited the answer to do that too!

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex pattern

```
^/([a-zA-Z]+[a-bA-Z0-9]+)/?.$
```

This will give you the root path with an extra condition that first letter should be a letter

If it can be a number too, you can simply use-

```
^/([a-bA-Z0-9]+)/?.$
```